# JavaFX + Xvfb - Yet another Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99"

Tags: ubuntu, javafx, xvfb

I have an ubuntu headless server with JavaFX and Xfvb up and running. Now I have a very similar Ubuntu server and try to get my JavaFX App running with Xvfb. But I allways get an exception thrown:

```
Prism ES2 Error - nInitialize: glXChooseFBConfig failed
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
```

Usually I could solve xrandr exception by exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ But not this time. I really have no idea what is wrong ...

This is how I usually start the server:

```
xvfb-run -a java -cp build/classes:lib/*:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar kic.engine.thrift.Server
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test JavaFX 2 in a headless environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194436/how-to-test-javafx-2-in-a-headless-environment)

Comment: How did you solve this issue ? please help me too

Comment: @Sundara finally the only solution was to install a X-Server :-(

Comment: thanks. what is the command for installing x-server in ubuntu?

Comment: @Sundara please use a search engine! this time I will do this for you:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/213678/how-to-install-x11-xorg

Comment: This is still listed as unanswered. Maybe you could reply with the solution and mark it as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java 8 one can use monocle for headless JavaFX. A useful example implementation (which at least helped me) could be found in the [ui4j](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j)  github project [ApplicationLauncher](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j/blob/3ee377f58f41850e0f72ae78e9767c619d8c939c/ui4j-webkit/src/main/java/com/ui4j/webkit/ApplicationLauncher.java).