# JavaFX in server with no X

Tags: java, linux, javafx

Hi want to use javaFX in a linux server without X to create screenshot of webpages but when I run it, it says this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/user/jre1.7.0_51/lib/amd64/libglass.so: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

now I wanted to know is there any way to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279336/javafx-in-headless-mode) can help?

Comment: thanks but didn't work!

Comment: Did you look at this question as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194436/how-to-test-javafx-2-in-a-headless-environment